# Using decltype to get an expression's type, without the const

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Consider the following program:

```
int main ()
{
    const int e = 10;

    for (decltype(e) i{0}; i < e; ++i) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with clang (as well as gcc):

```
decltype.cpp:5:35: error: read-only variable is not assignable
    for (decltype(e) i{0}; i < e; ++i) {
                                  ^ ~
```

Basically, the compiler is assuming that `i` must be const, since `e` is.

Is there a way I can use `decltype` to get the type of `e`, but removing the `const` specifier?

Comment: @KerrekSB auto doesn't work here either.  It will give me an `int`, regardless of whether `e` is an `int`.

Comment: `for (auto end = e, i = 0; i != end; ++i)`...

Comment: @KerrekSB With that I get `inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’` if `e` is anything other than `int`.

Comment: @KerrekSB That won't neccessarily work, since all types deduced in a "comma separated auto declaration" have to be the same.

Comment: @ChristianRau: What about `auto end = e, i {}`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Doesn't look so good idea, but I don't know, I have to admit.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I prefer `auto i = decltype(e){0};` for this. It's a bit simpler than using `type_traits`, and I feel it more explicitly specifies the intent that you want a variable initialized to a 0 of `e`'s type.

I've been using [Herb's "AAA Style"](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) a lot lately, so it could just be bias on my part.

Comment: This is excellent.  It answers the real question I was after with a concise syntax.

Comment: Would this make an extra call to any constructor of `delctype(e)`? Or is that the kind of thing that C++11 fixed?

Comment: `decltype(e){}` would be more general.

Answer (score 53):

Use [`std::remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv):

```
#include<type_traits>
...
for (std::remove_const<decltype(e)>::type i{0}; i < e; ++i)
```

Comment: Or `std::remove_const_t<decltype(e)> i{0}` with C++14

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
#include<type_traits>
...
for (std::decay<decltype(e)>::type i{}; i < e; ++i) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Should be `typename std::decay<decltype(e)>::type`. C++14 added an alias to shorten this, `std::decay_t<decltype(e)>`

Answer (score 9):

A solution not mentioned yet:

```
for (decltype(+e) i{0}; i < e; ++i)
```

Prvalues of primitive type have `const` stripped; so `+e` is a prvalue of type `int` and therefore `decltype(+e)` is `int`.

Comment: This forces the type to be `int` instead of removing the `const` from a generic type. Still, cool trick!

Comment: @CameronTacklind I guess you refer to integer promotions being applied -- smaller types than `int` are promoted to `int` but other types are unchanged. If `e` is `long` then `i` is `long` (not `int`).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer range-for. Simulate it is very easy.

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
struct range_t
{
    struct iter
    {
        T operator * ()const noexcept { return n;}
        iter& operator ++()noexcept{ ++n; return *this;}
        friend
        bool operator != (iter const& lhs, iter const& rhs)noexcept
        { return lhs.n != rhs.n;}

        T n;
    };

    iter begin()const noexcept {return {b};}
    iter end() const noexcept{ return {e};}
    T b, e;
};
template< typename T > range_t<T>  range(T b, T e){ return {b,e}; }

int main()
{
    const int e = 10;

    for( auto i : range(0,e) )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I don't like with this approach is the boiler-plate code for such a simple application. Now, it can be useful in other contexts.

Comment: I cannot see a compiler creating just as efficient code for this as for a normal for-loop. @greendiod you only have to declare the boilerplate once.

Comment: @LucBloom With optimizations enabled, g++ outputs the same assembly for both range-based for and normal for: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cKrcbx)